# C# WCF config file end point element

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config

I have a project that has a web service reference. I also have an `app.config` file that contains the binding information and endpoint. In one of my classes I'm invoking the the soap client object generated by the web service reference. I can initialize the soap client object to one of the endpoint I created in the `app.config` file. My confusion is with the constructor that takes in two strings. One is for the endpoint name in the `app.config` file and the other is the remote address. Why would I want to provide a remote address when I could just specifie it in the app.config file under the endpoint element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And what if you'd like this address to be dynamic?

You surely DO wish to have an constructor taking the remote address as a parameter rather than sticking only with a static configuration.

The constructor which takes both the binding and the endpoint address gives you most flexibility. We often delete the static configuration from the configuration files and create the proxy instances using this particular, two-argument constructor.

This way, it's easiest to dynamically relocate your application without the need to touch anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's an overload if you for some reason don't want to specify your configuration in the app.config file, it could be that you are storing it in a database or some other configuration mechanism.